# After a week of smooth running, my Dell t310 servername reverted to the service tag and screwed everything up!

Tags: windows, dell-poweredge, windows-sbs-2011

Has this happened to anyone else? Began having a tremedous amount of problems with our brand new Dell SBS 2011 T310 server and after nearly 15 hours will Dell support, they determined that the server name hade reverted to DXXXXXXXX ("D: + the service tag). The Dell tech said that this was a major major problem. I'm the only person with any access to the machine and I didn't attempt to change the server name. The tech said it didn't look as if anyone had hacked the box but something had replaced "OurCompanyServer" with "DXX12XX"

It would seem to me, simply changing the server name back to what I originally had would correct the problem, but the Dell tech said it wasn't that easy.

Anyone encounter this?

Comment: Look in the event log for when the computer name changed.  I can't imagine the system changed it arbitrarily..

Comment: Did the server come with SBS2011 pre-installed? If so, was the server name in fact D+the service tag?

Comment: the initial name change probably didn't work as expected!

Comment: @Shane - Looking for it. Haven't found it yet.
@joe - Yes everything came preinstalled and I ran through the setup wizards in about an hour to get it up and running initially. It was nearly perfect for a week or so. 
@Tony - I assuming you're correct tony. I am the only one with access to the server and I know damn well I didn't attempt to change it.

Comment: I've had strange corruptions with Dell Machines that have come preinstalled with the OS. One time in fact, Dell seemed to have left the install media in the server. The disk was scratched to no end. Ever since then, we've always just reinstalled the servers we get from Dell.

Comment: So, I'm sensing that you guys are essentially recommending that I reinstall from scratch and forego any sort recovery attempt. I have local copies of all the websites, I can export the sql server data and all of the workstations have local copies of their exchange accounts that I can export to a pst. Setting up all the user accounts and workstations again wouldn't take long... For future integrity-sake I'm feeling the total reinstall. yeah/nay?

Comment: okay, I tried restoring to the last backup. And everything works perfect again. Though I'd love to know how/what changed the computer name. Closest record I've found in the logs happens after a shutdown request preceded by 4 windows updates. 3:48:48 AM server name was correct - 3:48:50 AM Windows Update receives a shutdown request - 3:48:52 AM server name reverted to D+service tag